# How to add "Edit with gVim Easy" context menu item in Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

I originally just wanted to change the context menu item:

> Edit with Vim

to

> Edit with gVim Easy

and adjust the respective command appropriately.

But since I found out, some [DLL is responsible on the Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_Vim_to_MS-Windows_File_Explorer_Menu), I decided to leave the original item in place and create a new, separate one.

---

Requirements to summarize:

- gVim has to be run in Easy mode
- The context menu item should have an icon
- I would like not to define file types, let's make it for all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Before you do this, ensure you have the right path to the executable on your system!

---

It is as easy as saving the following code with minor adjustments for your personal needs into a file with `.reg` extension and running it, for this you will need administrator privileges:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\gVim]
@="Edit with &gVim Easy"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\gVim\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe\" -y \"%1\""
```

## Parsing

> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\gVim]
> ```

- The asterisk (`*`) means it applies to all files
- You can name it as you wish, I named it `gVim`, this won't be visible anywhere

> ```
> @="Edit with &gVim Easy"
> ```

- This on the contrary will be visible in all files' context menu
- You can name it as you wish, just add the ampersand (`&`) at some place, this will be the context menu keyboard key

> ```
> "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"
> ```

- This is the path to an icon-containing file, which I just wanted there, it is completely optional

> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\gVim\command]
> ```

- This is self-explanatory sub-menu `command`

> ```
> @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe\" -y \"%1\""
> ```

- Finally the executed command, you may adjust it with or without the easy mode switch (`-y`)